# :not(:empty) with space in CSS

Tags: css

I would like to apply a CSS rule on a div when it is empty. Problem: the application which generate the html puts a space:

```
<div class="my-div"> </div>
```

So I tried:

```
.my-div:not(:empty) {...}
```

But it doesn't work because of the space.

How can I do that in CSS ?

Thank you

Comment: If your application can generate a space can't it generate a specific class on those items? I can't think of a CSS way to do this if the `div` is not empty.

Comment: Why don't you change the application that generates the HTML or do some preprocessing?

Comment: @BeatAlex: That's because the div *only* contains whitespace and that whitespace is collapsed so the div has zero height. It still doesn't actually match the selector.

Comment: You are correct! @BoltClock I'll shut up now...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### You cant

(unfortunately)

The `:empty` selector is the [only way in CSS of detecting content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3aempty), and also proves positive for whitespace:

> The :empty pseudo-class represents any element that has no children at
>   all. Only element nodes and text (**including whitespace**) are
>   considered. Comments or processing instructions do not affect whether
>   an element is considered empty or not.

Dont forget about the separation of concerns, HTML for content, CSS for styling and JS for functionality - as such, you either need to remove the whitespace from your HTML (content) or apply a class depending on its presence, or strip it using JS (functionality).

With that said, elements only containing whitespace should collapse by default, so long as the space in question isnt a non-breaking space

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/v56Z7/)

Answer (score 1):

May be you try this;

```
.my.div{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
}
```

If the div is empty, otherwise you should set a another class by javascript if get content

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot do this with CSS ... here are 3 javascript lines that implements a CSS content selector called ":hasText" in jQuery.

```
$.expr[':']['hasText'] = function(node, index, props){
  return node.textContent == props[3];
};
```

You can use it in your problem like this:

```
$('.my-div:hasText(" ")').css({
  'background': 'red',
  'other css rules': '...'
});
```

Here is a [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/qiwuc/1/edit) with that same code implemented.